# I suddenly can no longer deploy my GoLang app to Google AppEngine

Tags: go, google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform

From one day to another I suddenly could no longer deploy my GoLang project to AppEngine. I get this error message in the log:

```
Step #2 - "build": Status: Downloaded newer image for eu.gcr.io/gae-runtimes/buildpacks/google-gae-18/go/builder:go_20230305_RC00
Step #2 - "build": eu.gcr.io/gae-runtimes/buildpacks/google-gae-18/go/builder:go_20230305_RC00
Step #2 - "build": ===> ANALYZING
Step #2 - "build": ERROR: failed to initialize analyzer: getting previous image: getting config file for image "eu.gcr.io/staticform/app-engine-tmp/app/www/ttl-18h:latest": GET https://storage.googleapis.com/eu.artifacts.staticform.appspot.com/containers/images/sha256:af3ff480dc0053108a52bf8b7ec3e45893e4e97c507102ff524b07bc01e03249?access_token=REDACTED: unexpected status code 404 Not Found: <?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?><Error><Code>NoSuchKey</Code><Message>The specified key does not exist.</Message><Details>No such object: eu.artifacts.staticform.appspot.com/containers/images/sha256:af3ff480dc0053108a52bf8b7ec3e45893e4e97c507102ff524b07bc01e03249</Details></Error>
Finished Step #2 - "build"
ERROR
ERROR: build step 2 "eu.gcr.io/gae-runtimes/buildpacks/google-gae-18/go/builder:go_20230305_RC00" failed: step exited with non-zero status: 1
```

First I thought Go 1.11 was finally deactivated but changing to 1.19 didn't solve the problem. It seems deploying with a new service name works but updating an existing service does not. Even when I change the service version.

I tested it with two of my GoLang projects (one without any changes). My Java projects deploy fine.

Here is my command to deploy:

```
gcloud app deploy --project=staticform --version=1 app.yaml
```

**Update:**

Here is my `app.yaml`:

```
runtime: go111
automatic_scaling:
  min_idle_instances: 0
  max_instances: 1

handlers:
  - url: /.*
    script: auto
    secure: always
  - url: /admin/.*
    script: auto
    secure: always
    login: admin
```

Comment: What's your app.yaml file content?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As it turned out all I needed was the `--no-cache` option. I don't know why, and I don't care. ;)

So with this command the deployment was successful:

```
gcloud app deploy --project=staticform --version=1 --no-cache app.yaml
```